# How to Listen to Contract Events in Drizzle

Tags: web3js, truffle, events, react, drizzle

Let's take the example of the `SimpleStorage` contract that comes with the truffle box [`drizzle-box`](https://github.com/truffle-box/drizzle-box)

How can we listen to the event `StorageSet` and `console.log` it to the JS console?

[**drizzleOptions.js**](https://github.com/truffle-box/drizzle-box/blob/master/src/drizzleOptions.js)

```
import SimpleStorage from './../build/contracts/SimpleStorage.json'

const drizzleOptions = {
web3: {
    block: false,
    fallback: {
    type: 'ws',
    url: 'ws://127.0.0.1:8545'
    }
},
contracts: [
    SimpleStorage
],
events: {
    SimpleStorage: ['StorageSet'],
},
polls: {
    accounts: 1500
}
}

export default drizzleOptions
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you use Metamask, so the problem might be the following: *"The current provider doesn't support subscriptions: MetamaskInpageProvider"*.

I don't either see this error message, since drizzle doesn't print it. You can have a look [here](https://github.com/trufflesuite/drizzle/blob/def2ad6c6ad28e64fb52f76a82c919dc06c6287f/src/contracts/contractsSaga.js#L59). On this way, you should be able to test that event subscription thing on your own/manually. Something like that:

```
drizzle.contracts.SimpleStorage.events
    .StorageSet({/* eventOptions */}, (error, event) => {
        console.log(error, event);
    })
    .on('data', (event) => console.log(event))
    .on('changed', (event) => console.log(event))
    .on('error', (error) => console.log(error));
```

[Here](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#contract-events) you can find the documentation for web3 events.

Optionally, you could check for events in the transaction receipt.

Comment: I can indeed reproduce this. I wonder how drizzle is useful in production where you only have MM as a provider? Did you find a solution @marius?

Answer (score 1):

I'm attempting to do a similar thing but from my understanding, Drizzle does not yet support this. Here's the issue I found to track it: https://github.com/trufflesuite/drizzle/issues/147